# Accidentally closed excel vba file without saving

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I was prototyping a vba macro and had two files with datasets. One was just dataset and the other was dataset with the macro. When I was about done for the day I selected the wrong file to close without noticing, and selected do not save on the pop-up as I didn't want to alter the dataset. Normally every time I test-run a macro it auto saves but when I reopen the dataset that should have the macro it didn't contain any vba modules or macros.

I'm using excel 2013.
Is there any way to recover the macro? That's like 3hr of code for me, I don't want to redo.
Also is there anyway to prevent this from happening in the future?

Edit: Solved, and thank you everyone that shared advice. As Emily's link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669726/forget-to-save-excel-macro provided a solution that best helped me in my case, but there were other advice given that I'm sure could help in similar situations. Thank you all.

To further clarify I started writing my macro in an .xlsx file and never once re-save in .xlsm format (file for excel macro) that is why the modules and macro didn't get auto-saved every time I test ran the macro. The link to similar issue showed where a temp copy of the .xlsx with modules could be found, and this time I got lucky.

Comment: Better share the Workbook with us to examine that what went wrong,, or at least share both the macro to analyse the situation !

Comment: I am afraid you need to rewrite your code. I find someone has raised the similar thread "[Forget to save excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669726/forget-to-save-excel-macro)", and they said it is not possible to restore unsaved macros.​​​​​​​

Comment: Sorry, I can't share file as I've sign non-disclosure for datasets. But thank you Emily, in the link Mathieu Guindon's comment help me find a temp file so I don't have to start from scratch. Thank you all for advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Office 2010 and Higher**

In Office 2010 and higher, you have an additional option, built in to the product, called Recover Unsaved Spreadsheets

- Click on File tab in the upper left corner.
- Choose Recent
- In the bottom left corner is Recover Unsaved Spreadsheets

The Saved Drafts folder will open. Find your file and double click on it to open. Then save the file.

These files can also be found in the following locations:

Windows 8/Windows 7/Windows Vista

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles
```

Windows XP

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles
```

**Other Useful Information**

If you have been working on a file for hours and the document was created via copying and pasting or at one point had cut the entire page or document to paste some place and then placed something else on the clip board, the data may not have been lost. This is because when any info is copied it is sent to a temp file with the name ~wrlxxxx.tmp. Therefore you could search your system for files of this name and then use the same "Drag and Drop" technique to view the data in Notepad to recover the data.

Another interesting thing to note is that when a change is made to a document that requires a temp file to be created, when you press the save button all the temp files are merged together into one file and the file is renamed to what you called it. The original document that you created is then deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately that folder was blank. I guess I forgot to mention I did check there, although it's been useful many time it seems to only save when system crashes, and this time it was a proper close, and do not save prompt. That tmp trick is definitely good FYI, thank you for all your help.